# How to ceate a point layer from a table in PostGIS?

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql

I have a table in PostgreSQL(postgis). This table has latitude and longitude values in it.
Now I want to plot these point in qgis. The only thing I could get done was connecting to the database from QGIS.

Could anyone please let me know on how to go about it.Thank You.

Here is the screenshot below[image]

Below is the connection error I get while connection to the database from QGIS
[image]

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking, is the problem that you cannot view your points in qgis? are your lats and lons separate fields in your table, or have you inserted them as a geometry?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your problem is that you do not have a geometry column. You could either find out how to get QGIS to display lon/lat fields, ad  GIS-Jonathan mentioned was possible, or you could create a geometry-column (assuming that all your lon/lat fields are non-empty:

First, [add a geometry column](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/AddGeometryColumn.html):

```
SELECT AddGeometryColumn ('public','growth','the_geom',4326,'POINT',2);
```

Then insert geometries created from the lon/lat fields:

```
UPDATE growth SET the_geom = GeomFromEWKT('SRID=4326;POINT(' || growth.longitude || ' ' || growth.latitude || ')');
```

(taken from [here](http://postgis.refractions.net/pipermail/postgis-users/2006-February/011039.html))

Comment: Thanks. But due to lack of db knowledge I get an error now.

ERROR:  function addgeometrycolumn(unknown, unknown, unknown, integer, unknown, integer) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT AddGeometryColumn ('public','growth','the_geom',4326,...
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

********** Error **********

Comment: It seems like you haven't installed PostGIS or "spatially enabled" your database, the lack of any functions and the geometry_columns table are clues. Could you try running: SELECT postgis_lib_version()

Comment: 1.5.3 is version

Comment: The first syntax works fine now and I get a new error for the second one :)

ERROR:  parse error - invalid geometry
HINT:  "SRID =4326;POINT(" <-- parse error at position 17 within geometry

********** Error **********

ERROR: parse error - invalid geometry
SQL state: XX000

Comment: Glad it worked in the end!

Comment: Well I came with another error for which I have posted another question.

http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24004/error-while-rendering-a-layer-from-postgresql-in-mapserver

Answer (score 2):

This tutorial should answer your question: [Working with your PostGIS Layers using Quantum GIS (QGIS)](http://gistutor.com/quantum-gis/20-intermediate-quantum-gis-tutorials/34-working-with-your-postgis-layers-using-quantum-gis-qgis.html)

 - from *Viewing PostGIS Layers using QGIS* about half way down.

Comment: Per @atlefren comment - if you haven't loaded the data correctly (it will need to be a `geometry` type to do this, though there are ways to do it if its just lat/lon fields) the first part of that tutorial does cover loading the data.

Comment: Yes this is what I was looking for. But the table which was created just has a few fields with no lat longs. Now when I check the option for list geometryless tables it doesnt display this table .

Comment: Ok, I have posted the screenshot

Comment: I can't tell on there, but are your latitude and longitude stored as strings or numbers? I imagine QGIS won't like them if they're not a suitable number type which may be your problem.

Answer (score 1):

in qgis press **Add PostGIS Layer** button then connect your postgis connection(if you dont have create new database connection), select your table and the last thing press Add button.

i hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

If your table only has lat and long data, you will need to create a geometry column out of them. I recommend using the qgis plugin "Fast SQL Layer" and then (assuming your table structure has the columns id as integer, lat as float, lng as float and the data is in WGS84) get a new layer using

```
SELECT id as gid, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(lng, lat), 4326) as the_geom FROM your_table;
```