# MapServer throws "msQueryByPoint(): Search returned no results."

Tags: postgresql, mapserver, ms4w

I have been trying to configure a QUERY using MapServer (through MS4W, on Windows). Below is the mapfile:

```
 MAP
 NAME "Fourth"                         
 UNITS dd                              
 EXTENT 58.206740 5.756104 104.793418 33.644106        
 SIZE 640 320                          
 IMAGECOLOR 200 225 255                
 IMAGETYPE gif                        

 FONTSET "C:\ms4w\Apache\htdocs\fontset.txt" # pointers to fonts


WEB
# A header/footer defined in a web object is displayed 
# before/after any individual query response is made. 
# It is displayed only once. 
#
HEADER "C:/ms4w/Apache/htdocs/xxx/map/fourth_web_header.html"
FOOTER "C:/ms4w/Apache/htdocs/xxx/map/fourth_web_footer.html"

TEMPLATE "C:/ms4w/Apache/htdocs/xxx/map/fourth.html"          
IMAGEPATH "C:/ms4w/Apache/htdocs/tmp/"
IMAGEURL "/tmp/"                        
  END


LEGEND
IMAGECOLOR 255 255 255
STATUS ON
KEYSIZE 14 12
LABEL
  TYPE BITMAP
  SIZE SMALL
  COLOR 0 0 89
  END
 END

QUERYMAP                     
STATUS on                # draw query map
STYLE hilite             # highlight selected feature
COLOR 255 255 0          # in yellow
SIZE 320 160
END

SYMBOL

NAME "circle"
TYPE ellipse # Type of symbol

POINTS
1 1
END # end of POINTS

FILLED true
END 


LAYER
NAME 'growth_1'
TYPE POINT
DUMP true
TEMPLATE fooOnlyForWMSGetFeatureInfo
# A header or footer defined at the layer level is displayed
# if that layer is a query layer. It is displayed only once.
#
HEADER "C:/ms4w/Apache/htdocs/xxx/map/fourth_cities_header.html"
FOOTER "C:/ms4w/Apache/htdocs/xxx/map/fourth_cities_footer.html"

TOLERANCE 1             # must be within 1 tolerance unit
TOLERANCEUNITS miles    # units for tolerance values is miles

EXTENT 58.206740 5.756104 104.793418 33.644106
CONNECTIONTYPE postgis
CONNECTION "dbname='postgis' host=localhost port=5432 user='postgres' password='xxxxxxx' sslmode=disable"
DATA 'the_geom FROM "growth_1" USING srid=4326'
METADATA
  'ows_title' 'growth_1'
END
STATUS ON
TRANSPARENCY 100
PROJECTION
'proj=longlat'
'datum=WGS84'
'no_defs'
END


CLASSITEM 'growth_scale'
CLASS
  NAME "growth_scale = BAD" 
  EXPRESSION "BAD" 
   STYLE
     SYMBOL "circle" 
     SIZE 7.0 
     OUTLINECOLOR 0 0 0
     COLOR 242 115 240
   END
END
CLASS
  NAME "growth_scale = EXCELLENT" 
  EXPRESSION "EXCELLENT" 
   STYLE
     SYMBOL "circle" 
     SIZE 7.0 
     OUTLINECOLOR 0 0 0
     COLOR 53 116 77
   END
END
CLASS
  NAME "growth_scale = FAIR" 
  EXPRESSION "FAIR" 
   STYLE
     SYMBOL "circle" 
     SIZE 7.0 
     OUTLINECOLOR 0 0 0
     COLOR 92 200 4
   END
END
CLASS
  NAME "growth_scale = GOOD" 
  EXPRESSION "GOOD" 
   STYLE
     SYMBOL "circle" 
     SIZE 7.0 
     OUTLINECOLOR 0 0 0
     COLOR 94 8 202
   END
END
CLASS
  NAME "growth_scale = MARGINALLY BAD" 
  EXPRESSION "MARGINALLY BAD" 
   STYLE
     SYMBOL "circle" 
     SIZE 7.0 
     OUTLINECOLOR 0 0 0
     COLOR 252 63 172
   END
END
CLASS
  NAME "growth_scale = NO DATA" 
  EXPRESSION "NO DATA" 
   STYLE
     SYMBOL "circle" 
     SIZE 7.0 
     OUTLINECOLOR 0 0 0
     COLOR 22 79 25
   END
END
CLASS
  NAME "growth_scale = POOR" 
  EXPRESSION "POOR" 
   STYLE
     SYMBOL "circle" 
     SIZE 7.0 
     OUTLINECOLOR 0 0 0
     COLOR 86 98 176
   END
END
CLASS
  NAME "growth_scale = VERY GOOD" 
  EXPRESSION "VERY GOOD" 
   STYLE
     SYMBOL "circle" 
     SIZE 7.0 
     OUTLINECOLOR 0 0 0
     COLOR 189 72 76
   END


CLASS
    # A template defined at the class level is used to display
    # the results for each reponse to a query. If a result set
    # contains N, then the template will be used N times.
    #
    TEMPLATE "C:/ms4w/Apache/htdocs/xxx/map/fourth_cities_query.html"
    STYLE
        COLOR 0 0 0     # symbol color is black
    END
       
END


END 

END
```

But then when I go the query mode I get the following error:

> msQueryByPoint(): Search returned no results. No matching record(s) found.

Any idea on why such an error message?

Now from this morning I get this window but the attribute is not populated.
[image]

The following is the query template

```
  <!--Mapserver Template-->
  <font size+1><b>Layer:growth_1</b></font>
  <tr><td>[lrn]</td>
  <td>[code]</td>
  <td>[address]</td>
  <td>[latitude]</td>
  <td>[longitude]</td>
  <th>bbbbb</th>
  <th>scale</th>
  <th>oid</th></tr>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**First of all a few doc pointers**

The mapserver documentation addresses this error at:

http://mapserver.org/errors.html#msreturnpage-web-application-error-malformed-template-name

For an explanation of url templates see this [doc](http://mapserver.org/mapfile/template.html).

**Answer**

It seems like you are now a GetFeatureInfo query and using a fooOnlyForWmsGetFeatureInfo template which is missing the proper extension.

The list of allowed extensions is documented in the code here:

https://github.com/mapserver/mapserver/blob/master/mapserver.h#L245

So basically you have edit the mapfile so that this section:

```
  LAYER
  NAME 'growth_1'
  TYPE POINT
  DUMP true
  TEMPLATE fooOnlyForWMSGetFeatureInfo
```

becomes:

```
  LAYER
  NAME 'growth_1'
  TYPE POINT
  DUMP true
  TEMPLATE path/to/your_template.html
```

**Final note**

BTW, your template contains invalid html:

```
<font size+1>
```

should be:

```
<font size="+1">
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume something is wrong with your query template. Perhaps fields defined in the query template do not exist in the table.  Have a look at this [mapserver tutorial](http://demo.mapserver.org/cgi-bin/mapserv?root=/tutorial&program=/cgi-bin/mapserv&map=/osgeo/mapserver/tutorial/htdocs/example3.map&layer=states&zoom=0&map_web=template%20example3-1.html&submit=Go%20there!) which should help